# How to close an Activity in onReceive()

Tags: java, android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I'm stating a new Activity in **onReceive()** like this.

```
context.startActivity(new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class));
```

But can't close the activity directly in **onReceive()**.

I have a static variable which stores the reference to the new Activity.

(the context is assigned in **onCreate()** of the Activity)

So I'm calling **finish()** in **onReceive()** like this.

```
SecondActivity.context.finish();
```

But I don't think this is a good way. Is there a better approach for this?

I know I can just call **finish()** directly in **onReceive()** if my **BroadcastReceiver** is defined within an Activity class, but the problem is, it'll close 'this' Activity but not the Activity newly created in **onReceive()**. And also can't call **finish()** when the Broadcast Receiver is static, not dynamic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm stating a new Activity in onReceive() like this.

That is a strong code smell, unless this is a local broadcast (`LocalBroadcastManager`), in which case it is a weaker code smell.

> I have a static variable which stores the reference to the new Activity.

That is a strong code smell.

> And also can't call finish() when the Broadcast Receiver is static, not dynamic.

Changing the mix of activities based on a system broadcast is another strong code smell.

> Is there a better approach for this?

Given all the code smells, I suspect that you have significant architectural problems with your app.

That being said, the general approach is *not* to have outside parties control activities this way. Instead, you use an event bus (`LocalBroadcastManager`, greenrobot's EventBus) to raise an event. The activity, if it exists, can listen for those events and take appropriate action, which might include destroying itself. Alternatively, it is possible that reactive solutions (RxJava/RxAndroid, etc.) might help here, where on receipt of the broadcast you do something that triggers an observer registered by the activity.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and advice!